# Detect Usage of Specific Methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio I would like to know whether code in a project uses certain methods. For example, we would like to know that "==" is being used in string comparisons, as we have a team rule that only ".Equals" should be used when comparing strings.

Do any tools exist to accomplish this goal?

Comment: ReSharper can do this.

Comment: You could create a custom rule in FxCop.

Comment: Off topic, but I'm curious why you have that rule.

Comment: curious about 'as we have a team rule that only ".Equals" should be used when comparing strings'. Change that rule to use string.compare

Comment: We have the rule because of things like the Turkish "I", as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx

Comment: We use the .Equals instead of .Compare for performance. We only need to know equals or not. Reflecting the code shows that .Equals has a lot less to do than .Compare.

Answer (score 3):

Given the following code block

```
var x = "s" == "a";
var y = 1 == 2;
var z = "a" == "b";
```

If I right-click on the first `==` and click `Find Usage`, I get the following results.
[image: Find usage of string ==]

If I right-click on the second `==` and click `Find Usage`, I get a tool-tip that states `This is the only usage`.

I'm not sure what features it has, but there is a new free command-line version of ReSharper.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/command-line.html